# Please assist in using the below code to have a tab open by default, preferably the first tab called 'Overview'

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code works fine but I need to have the first tab open by default.

After trying a few solutions from Stack Overflow, none of the code seems to work or is not compatible with my Javascript.

The code inserted from Stack overflow is:

```
onload="document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();)
```

This was applied within the first tab opening and closes tags.

Code can be viewed here:

https://codepen.io/BradleyPuckree/pen/WqVNRw

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 215px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
}
  
  
  .tab button {
    background-color: inherit;

    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <button
            class="tablinks"
            onload="document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();)"
        >
            Overview
        </button>

        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'learn')">
            What You Will Learn
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'content')">
            Programme Content
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'path')">
            Career Path
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="overview" class="tabcontent">
        <p>
            A broad scope of management and marketing knowledge Economics,
            financial management and general management principles Business
            communication, marketing research and marketing activities How
            to solve marketing problems in organisations Marketing ethics
            and management values How to create a strategic marketing plan A
            broad understanding of business management Evaluation methods to
            ensure good decision-making
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="learn" class="tabcontent">
        <p>
            The IMM BBA Degree empowers students with graduate-level
            knowledge, specific skills and applied competence in the field
            of Marketing and Business Management to enable them to pursue
            practical and rewarding careers in the business marketing
            environment. Students will also gain an intermediate competence
            in marketing, business management and financial management.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 1</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Marketing 1</li>
                    <li>Academic Literacy</li>
                    <li>Business Communication</li>
                    <li>Business Management 1</li>
                    <li>Business Statistics</li>
                    <li>Economic Principles</li>
                    <li>Financial Management 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 2 </strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Marketing 2</li>
                    <li>Brand Management</li>
                    <li>Sales Manager</li>
                    <li>Business Management 2</li>
                    <li>Financial Management 2</li>
                    <li>Integrated Marketing Communications</li>
                    <li>Marketing Research: Theory</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 3</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Marketing 3</li>
                    <li>Business Management 3</li>
                    <li>Business Project</li>
                    <li>Financial Management 3</li>
                    <li>Global Marketing</li>
                    <li>Marketing Research: Project 3</li>
                    <li>Elective 1</li>
                    <li>Elective 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="path" class="tabcontent">
        <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Career Path</strong></p>
        <ul>
            <li>Brand Manager</li>
            <li>Store Manager</li>
            <li>Sales Manager</li>
            <li>Brand Co-ordinator</li>
            <li>Customer Service</li>
            <li>Database Management</li>
            <li>Digital Marketing</li>
            <li>Direct Marketing</li>
            <li>Events and Promotional Management</li>
            <li>Market Research</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I keep the first tab open by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to initialized the first style.
On bellow code, I'm removing the onload function, add `style="display: block"` to `#overview.tabcontent` and add `active` class to overview button

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 215px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
  
  
  .tab button {
  background-color: inherit;

  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'overview')">Overview</button>
  
  
  
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'learn')">What You Will Learn</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'content')">Programme Content</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'path')">Career Path</button>
</div>

<div id="overview" class="tabcontent" style="display: block">

  <p>A broad scope of management and marketing knowledge
Economics, financial management and general management principles
Business communication, marketing research and marketing activities
How to solve marketing problems in organisations
Marketing ethics and management values
How to create a strategic marketing plan
A broad understanding of business management
Evaluation methods to ensure good decision-making</p>
</div>

<div id="learn" class="tabcontent">
  <p>The IMM BBA Degree empowers students with graduate-level knowledge, specific skills and applied competence in the field of Marketing and Business Management to enable them to pursue practical and rewarding careers in the business marketing environment. Students will also gain an intermediate competence in marketing, business management and financial management.</p> 
</div>

<div id="content" class="tabcontent">

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 1</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 1</li>
<li>Academic Literacy</li>
<li>Business Communication</li>
<li>Business Management 1</li>
<li>Business Statistics</li>
<li>Economic Principles</li>
<li>Financial Management 1</li>
</ul>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 2 </strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 2</li>
<li>Brand Management</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Business Management 2</li>
<li>Financial Management 2</li>
<li>Integrated Marketing Communications</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Theory</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 3</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 3</li>
<li>Business Management 3</li>
<li>Business Project</li>
<li>Financial Management 3</li>
<li>Global Marketing</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Project 3</li>
<li>Elective 1</li>
<li>Elective 2</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
  
<div id="path" class="tabcontent">
 
<p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Career Path</strong></p>

<ul>
<li>Brand Manager</li>
<li>Store Manager</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Brand Co-ordinator</li>
<li>Customer Service</li>
<li>Database Management</li>
<li>Digital Marketing</li>
<li>Direct Marketing</li>
<li>Events and Promotional Management</li>
<li>Market Research</li>
</ul>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `defaultOpen` class to overview button and call `click` on `onload` attribute of the body, alternatively you could also do this inside `window.onload` event which is commented:

```js
/*window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName('defaultOpen')[0].click();
}*/

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 215px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
  
  
  .tab button {
  background-color: inherit;

  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementsByClassName('defaultOpen')[0].click();">

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks defaultOpen" onclick="openCity(event, 'overview')">Overview</button>  
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'learn')">What You Will Learn</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'content')">Programme Content</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'path')">Career Path</button>
</div>

<div id="overview" class="tabcontent">

  <p>A broad scope of management and marketing knowledge
Economics, financial management and general management principles
Business communication, marketing research and marketing activities
How to solve marketing problems in organisations
Marketing ethics and management values
How to create a strategic marketing plan
A broad understanding of business management
Evaluation methods to ensure good decision-making</p>
</div>

<div id="learn" class="tabcontent">
  <p>The IMM BBA Degree empowers students with graduate-level knowledge, specific skills and applied competence in the field of Marketing and Business Management to enable them to pursue practical and rewarding careers in the business marketing environment. Students will also gain an intermediate competence in marketing, business management and financial management.</p> 
</div>

<div id="content" class="tabcontent">

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 1</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 1</li>
<li>Academic Literacy</li>
<li>Business Communication</li>
<li>Business Management 1</li>
<li>Business Statistics</li>
<li>Economic Principles</li>
<li>Financial Management 1</li>
</ul>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 2 </strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 2</li>
<li>Brand Management</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Business Management 2</li>
<li>Financial Management 2</li>
<li>Integrated Marketing Communications</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Theory</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 3</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 3</li>
<li>Business Management 3</li>
<li>Business Project</li>
<li>Financial Management 3</li>
<li>Global Marketing</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Project 3</li>
<li>Elective 1</li>
<li>Elective 2</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
  
<div id="path" class="tabcontent">
 
<p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Career Path</strong></p>

<ul>
<li>Brand Manager</li>
<li>Store Manager</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Brand Co-ordinator</li>
<li>Customer Service</li>
<li>Database Management</li>
<li>Digital Marketing</li>
<li>Direct Marketing</li>
<li>Events and Promotional Management</li>
<li>Market Research</li>
</ul>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and explanation for the solution, this answer has successfully worked for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Modified script code:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].click();
}
```

You can change the index of link as per your need or one more thing you can do is:
Add an id to the button you want as default

Like below:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" id="default" onload="document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();)">Overview</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'learn')">What You Will Learn</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'content')">Programme Content</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'path')">Career Path</button>
</div>
```

And modify the script like below:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('default').click();
}
```

It would also work.

Answer (score 0):

add `style="display:block"` to id overview and class active to the overview button

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Poppins,sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 215px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #6bc048;
  color:white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
  
  
  .tab button {
  background-color: inherit;

  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'overview')">Overview</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'learn')">What You Will Learn</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'content')">Programme Content</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'path')">Career Path</button>
</div>

<div id="overview" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">

  <p>A broad scope of management and marketing knowledge
Economics, financial management and general management principles
Business communication, marketing research and marketing activities
How to solve marketing problems in organisations
Marketing ethics and management values
How to create a strategic marketing plan
A broad understanding of business management
Evaluation methods to ensure good decision-making</p>
</div>

<div id="learn" class="tabcontent">
  <p>The IMM BBA Degree empowers students with graduate-level knowledge, specific skills and applied competence in the field of Marketing and Business Management to enable them to pursue practical and rewarding careers in the business marketing environment. Students will also gain an intermediate competence in marketing, business management and financial management.</p> 
</div>

<div id="content" class="tabcontent">

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 1</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 1</li>
<li>Academic Literacy</li>
<li>Business Communication</li>
<li>Business Management 1</li>
<li>Business Statistics</li>
<li>Economic Principles</li>
<li>Financial Management 1</li>
</ul>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 2 </strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 2</li>
<li>Brand Management</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Business Management 2</li>
<li>Financial Management 2</li>
<li>Integrated Marketing Communications</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Theory</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  
  <p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Year 3</strong></p>
  
<ul>
<li>Marketing 3</li>
<li>Business Management 3</li>
<li>Business Project</li>
<li>Financial Management 3</li>
<li>Global Marketing</li>
<li>Marketing Research: Project 3</li>
<li>Elective 1</li>
<li>Elective 2</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
  
<div id="path" class="tabcontent">
 
<p class="green-tab-heading"><strong>Career Path</strong></p>

<ul>
<li>Brand Manager</li>
<li>Store Manager</li>
<li>Sales Manager</li>
<li>Brand Co-ordinator</li>
<li>Customer Service</li>
<li>Database Management</li>
<li>Digital Marketing</li>
<li>Direct Marketing</li>
<li>Events and Promotional Management</li>
<li>Market Research</li>
</ul>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```